# why CMSIS does not offer a functo to read an IRQ enable/disable status?

Tags: cmsis

functions NVIC_EnableIRQ and NVIC_DisableIRQ are meant to enable and disable interrupts on a given IRQ number. Why there is no function to get the current enable/disable status of that IRQ?

The use case is the typical function that needs to disable a module's interrupt (IRQ) before proceeding. After the function is done then it will enable the IRQ again. But to be sure one needs to read first whether the IRQ was enabled at the moment the function was called.

Given that the function is not provided by CMSIS then I assume that my use case above is somehow flawed. But I do not see how.

Any hints?

Thanks

(using CMSIS 4.1)

Answer (score 0):

I think your use case could make sense in some situations.

You'd have to create the function to read the enabled state of the IRQ by yourself.

You just need to make sure that no interrupt changes the enabled state between the reading of the enabled state and the actual disabling. In this case you would end up with setting the wrong enabled state after executing your function.

You can use `__disable_irq();` to globally disable all irqs (Keil Syntax):

```
bool isEnabled;
__disable_irq();
isEnabled = ReadIrqEnabledState(irqNr);
__enable_irq();

yourFunction();

if(isEnabled)
    NVIC_EnableIrq(irqNr);
else
    NVIC_DisableIrq(irqNr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function. It works fine...

```
inline bool IsIRQEnabled (IRQn_Type IRQn)
{
    return (0 != (NVIC->ISER[(uint32_t)((int32_t)IRQn) >> 5] & (uint32_t)(1 << ((uint32_t)((int32_t)IRQn) & (uint32_t)0x1F))));
}
```